# How to compile java project with external jar file in Linux terminal

Tags: java, jar, terminal

I have project which includes external jar file in it, I followed this link http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29 to add external java path. Then I tried to compile my code in terminal, however I am still get an error about jar file does not exist.

I wrote the following commands: (Currently I am in the project directory and there are three folders called bin src and lib in there)

```
bash-3.2$ ls
bin  lib  README.txt  src
bash-3.2$ javac -cp lib/jsoup-1.6.1.jar src/DayTradingStockBlog.java
bash-3.2$ java -cp .:lib/jsoup-1.6.1.jar src/DayTradingStockBlog
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: src/DayTradingStockBlog (wrong name: DayTradingStockBlog)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: src/DayTradingStockBlog.  Program will exit.
```

How should I solve this problem ?

Comment: What *exactly* does the error say?

Comment: package org.jsoup does not exist
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

Comment: I am compiling with the following code while in the src directory: javac myClass.java

Comment: You must set the classpath to contain your jar file..

Comment: `java -cp .; lib/jsoup-1.6.1.jar src/myClass` - Here surround whatever follows -cp or -classpath option with  double/single quotes. The semi-colon after the . (dot) indicates it's the end of the command and tries to execute whatever follows that as the next command. Hence the 'Permission denied' error.

Comment: BTW it is good idea for java class name to start from capital letter.

Comment: @CanCeylan, use ":" colon for classpath separator on Linux

Comment: please look at my edit in the question

Comment: @CanCeylan, you are trying to compile class with its name without the package, please try to use a fully-qualified-classpath for DayTradingStockBlog. (I guess there is some package structure under src, e.g com.somepackage.DayTradingStockBlog)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You never use slashes, which are path delimiters, in a call to java (but to javac). If src is part of your package declaration - in this case the whole package declaration, which I bet it is not, you would, instead of:

```
 java -cp .:lib/jsoup-1.6.1.jar src/DayTradingStockBlog
```

use a dot:

```
 java -cp .:lib/jsoup-1.6.1.jar src.DayTradingStockBlog
```

But I guess it is just the place where you created the class, so the path belongs to the classpath:

```
 java -cp .:lib/jsoup-1.6.1.jar:./src DayTradingStockBlog
```

You aren't free to omit the path from the Class name, and append it to the classpath, or vice versa - it has to fit to your package declaration.

If you declare a package `foo`, (which has much more sense than src), your class name is no longer `DayTradingStockBlog` but `foo.DayTradingStockBlog`.

Comment: +1 for the correct usage of invoking a 'packaged class' (using a dot).

Answer (score 2):

Based on your edit, I'd suggest you to enclose all classpath locations within single/double quotes. That is, make it like

`java -cp '.:lib/jsoup-1.6.1.jar' src/myClass`.

In linux, the items in the classpath are separated by a colon (:) and in Windows, it's a semicolon (;).

Comment: bash-3.2$ javac -cp lib/jsoup-1.6.1.jar src/myClass.java
bash-3.2$ java -cp .:lib/jsoup-1.6.1.jar src/myClass

Comment: I tried these to commands now, first one is working however for the second one it gives Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: src/myClass (wrong name: myClass)

Comment: @CanCeylan That's because myClass is not under the package src. You just made it up, I guess. Just make it myClass.

Comment: `cd src; javac -cp lib/jsoup-1.6.1.jar myClass.java; java -cp '.:lib/jsoup-1.6.1.jar' myClass`, just in case you've not got it right yet.

Answer (score 1):

use classpath (-cp)

```
javac -cp %YOUR_JAR_LOCATION% myClass.java
```

Comment: @CanCeylan go to the jar DIRECTORY (no folders in Linux) and provide the access permissions: chmod 777 ./jsoup-1.6.1.jar then run the javac again

Comment: @aviad That's not the problem. You don't want to make its permission go 777, just to have the library on the classpath.

Comment: @asgs, I am afraid that is a problem 'Permission denied' does not correlate with anything else that I am aware of. It is about making the the java class compile and not about teaching how permissions work on Linux.

Comment: @aviad See my comment directly under the question.

Comment: @CanCeylan, use ":" colon for classpath separator on Linux

Comment: @CanCeylan, you are trying to compile class with its name without the package, please try to use a fully-qualified-classpath for DayTradingStockBlog. (I guess there is some package structure under src, e.g com.somepackage.DayTradingStockBlog)

Answer (score -2):

you should place the java file and jar file in the same dir
example: javac -cp jdbc.jar myClass.java
it works for me

Comment: this is not useful, suppose if you have multiple programs all using same external JAR, do you make copies of JAR each time ?