# Proper place to put Postgres JDBC Driver (postgresql-42.1.4.jar) on linux

Tags: java, psql

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;


class Demopsql{

Demopsql()
{
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Where is your PostgreSQL JDBC Driver? "
                    + "Include in your library path!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;    
    }    
}
```

where should it be paste postgresql-42.1.4.jar or extracted at where?

so that program won't throw class not found exception.

Comment: Possible dublicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse

Comment: @MustafaÇil in linux

Comment: Which ide do you use? @noeg

Comment: @MustafaÇil not using any ide just linux terminal

Comment: It may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395207/how-to-include-jar-files-with-java-file-and-compile-in-command-prompt @noeg

Comment: @MustafaÇil output says javac :  no source files

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse, you can follow the method which is written on this post:
[Import Libraries in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962559/import-libraries-in-eclipse)
You will have to put it as an "external jar".

Or you can look at the maven project possibility:
https://maven.apache.org/
You will just have to create a maven project and put a dependency into a file (pom.xml). It will be downloaded when you will do a maven update operation on your project.
I give you the text which should be added to the pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
   <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
   <version>42.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a build tool like maven, add this jar as a dependency. Otherwise you have to make sure that this jar is accessible in classpath. In Eclipse go to project properties -> build path -> Libraries tab , you can find a button to Add External JARs. Add this JAR as external jar.

Comment: @EldhoseAbrahami am not using any ide just linux terminal

Comment: make sure this is accessible in classpath.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200334/how-to-compile-java-project-with-external-jar-file-in-linux-terminal 
should help.